# Arcane/obscure word that represents a person's timeline or daily record

Tags: vocabulary, single-word-requests

I'm looking for an arcane or obscure word to describe a person's daily record.

Words like:

> account, agenda, appointment book,
>   chronicle, diary, daily record,
>   daybook, engagement book, journal,
>   log, minutes, notebook, record

work, but are common. Do you have something more obscure?

Comment: _Arcane_ and _obscure_ seem subjective criteria, to me.

Comment: If you don't know the meaning of a posted answer, upvote it. The most arcane word will float to the top, and you'll have _objective_ proof of it. ;)

Comment: I will wait somebody writes an Old English word, then.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*Ephemeris* has an obsolete meaning synonymous with this, and it certainly has a solid arcane flavor to it.  Also rather lovely is *noctuary*, which is the opposite of "diary", logging what happens during the night rather than the day.

Answer (score 5):

How about the Latin ***libellus***.

It is used for any "little book", but specifically journals, diaries, logbooks, notebooks.

Answer (score 4):

It's not a very good fit in meaning, but **vade mecum** springs to mind - literally, it's Latin for "go with me", and it means a little book with useful information that you carry around with you. It *can* contain a section for daily notes and such, although that is not its primary purpose.

Answer (score 2):

Any of those would be rendered more recondite were you to add the adjective *quotidian* to them.

> **quotidian** of or occurring every day; daily : *the car sped noisily off through the quotidian traffic.*
>   • ordinary or everyday, esp. when mundane : *his story is an achingly human one, mired in quotidian details.*

So you might refer to someone's "quotidian chronicle" if you wanted to be all, like, abstruse & stuff.

Comment: I could always add modifiers, but I'm looking for a word that has fallen out of favor.

Answer (score 2):

'**Grimoire**' is more specifically an instruction book, particularly dark, used by alchemists or sorcerers, but could describe a diary or journal of a similarly dark person.

Similarly arcane is '**Book of Shadows**', as popularized by Gerald Gardner.

There is also '**apocryphon**', which means secret writing.  It has a strong tie to the early Christian movement, especially gnosticism.