# Word to describe "everyday things"

Tags: single-word-requests, vocabulary

Is there any one word which can describe *everyday things*?

By this, I mean things we commonly regard as things most people do every day, like taking a shower, brushing your teeth, getting dressed, going to work or school, and eating dinner.

Comment: Cousin question: _[Arcane/obscure word that represents a person's timeline or daily record](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/16030/5822)_.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

"Quotidian" is a good word, although it may be a little too highbrow.

> quo·tid·i·an /kwōˈtidēən/ adjective -[Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=Quotidian&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8)
>
> Of or occurring every day; daily. Ordinary or everyday, especially when mundane.

Comment: Well, if more people use it, it will stop seeming so highbrow!

Comment: Perfect! Thank you! That was exactly what I was looking for :)

Comment: When I saw this question I immediately thought of the Spanish word *cotidiano*, which is very common in that language.

Answer (score 31):

***routine:***

> noun
>   1. a customary or regular course of procedure.
>   2. commonplace tasks, chores, or duties as must be done regularly or at
>   specified intervals; typical or
>   everyday activity: the routine of an
>   office.
>   3. regular, unvarying, habitual, unimaginative, or rote procedure.

Answer (score 22):

The word ***mundane*** can be appropriate here, as it can be used to refer to things that are common or ordinary. Brushing your teeth or taking a shower are indeed *mundane* activities. Note that this can have a bit of a negative connotation, suggesting that the activities are common enough to be boring. If you want to avoid the negative connotation, ***routine*** (as suggested by gbutters) may be a better choice.

Comment: +1 as this was my answer also :)

Answer (score 4):

a word to describe everyday things.  Things is about as general a word as I can think of...how about

> commonplace

Answer (score 1):

If you mean activities, you could use *workaday*.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. We appreciate links to sources which support your answer. :-)

Answer (score 1):

I believe that this word greatly fits the definition of "everyday things."

> Commodities: Useful or valuable items. Usually very important necessities for life such as water or time, but its connotation fits very well.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. While your answer is fine, it would be improved by adding a link to your source, so that others can learn from it too.

Answer (score 1):

the *minutiae* of everyday life?

Answer (score 1):

You can call that your daily routine. And we know that a routine is a usual or fixed way of doing things that are done regularly at a specified intervals.

Comment: It would be good to cite a reference rather than letting this nice answer stand here as though it were just your own opinion.

Answer (score 0):

May I have the opportunity to add my version of the (not so) trite word:

> Hackneyed

Also consider a word called:

> Chore

usage: "..my daily chores"

Not to mention that the accepted answer is laconic in that I personally prefer its usage.

> "Jim got so engrossed in watching the soccer match that he forgot the
>   quotidian task of watering the plants."

Answer (score -2):

*Daily chores* might fit well here.

Comment: Please [edit] your answer to explain why it might fit well.